# Integrating swagger into ASP.NET core api project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have an ASP.NET core api project which I started in .NET core 3.1, then upgraded to 5.0. It did not previously have swagger integrated and I would now like to include it.

I have brought in the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` package v5.6.3. Reading through this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) I have modified my `Startup.cs` to include `services.AddSwaggerGen();` as well as `app.UseSwagger();` and `app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "DemoAPI"));` (the standard boilerplate stuff).

Relevant sections of `Startup.cs` (as they stand now):

```
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "DemoAPI",
                    Version = "v1"
                });
                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });
```

```
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "DemoAPI"));
            }
```

On startup I see:

[image: this]

Could someone help me to see what further setup I need to do here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example. You'll need to make sure xml comment file generation is turned on, and that you set the entryAssembly and apiVersion variables, i.e. "v1" or whatever you prefer.

Once you run, simply visit `/swagger` to see it all.

```cs
// Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    try
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc(apiVersion, new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = entryAssembly.GetName().Name, Version = apiVersion });
        foreach (string xmlCommentsFile in Directory.GetFiles(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "*.xml"))
        {
            try
            {
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlCommentsFile, true);
            }
            catch
            {
                // nothing to be done, fails in unit tests
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // nothing to be done, fails in unit tests
    }
});

// later on in app setup
// enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwagger();

// enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
// specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{apiVersion}/swagger.json", $"{entryAssembly.GetName().Name} {apiVersion}");
});
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't know about that try/catch - I appreciate that and will integrate it. I've updated my question to show that as far as I can see I think I am already doing what you are showing? Still getting the error though.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is your xml documentation code is slightly different and maybe those files aren't being output as you expect

Comment: I appreciate that @jjxtra, but I think maybe we're getting off the mark a bit? What appears to be missing is not the xml files so much but a file called swagger.json? The odd thing is, I spun up a new .NET 5.0 webapi project and by default, everything just works - but there doesn't appear to be any swagger.json anywhere in the generated files that I can find.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found what was going on. In my case I had a couple of endpoints with routes in the existing project which did not have `[HttpGet]` attributes. This was causing swagger to error out. Once I fixed that, things are up and running now.